# Using "map" in scheme language without procedure?

Tags: lisp, scheme

I have a question about the usage of "map" - Here is the piece of code,

```
(for-each 
   (lambda (x) (if (member x sb-id-list) (set! si-exists? #t)))
   (append (map thread-id sb1-thread) (map thread-id sb2-thread)))
```

First of all, I'm sure this code is working correctly - It's taken from the source code of a solver. What I don't understand is that I don't see a "procedure" for the "map" here? Is this some witty usage of map I don't know of? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My assumption is that "thread-id" is some sort of procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Kevin mentioned, `thread-id` is a procedure which takes the `sb1-thread` parameter